# Text doesn't wrap in <div> and <lightning-card>

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-card

I have a little problem, text inside tags doesn't wrap (I don't use `<p>` and write text in `<div>`).

HTML is very simple, but I can't solve the problem:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-center">
        <lightning-card class="slds-size_1-of-3">
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <h1 class="slds-text-align_center">Card question</h1>
                <div>adwadwwdawdwadwadawdawdawdawddwawdadwdawdawdwadadwdadawdwdadwadawddawdwadawdadawd</div>
                <div class="slds-m-top_small slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_destructive">Show</button>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_success">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
    </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add CSS to wrap the text.

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

define a class in CSS file

```
.wrapped-content{
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

And add this class to the div.

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-center">
        <lightning-card class="slds-size_1-of-3">
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <h1 class="slds-text-align_center">Card question</h1>
                <div class="wrapped-content">adwadwwdawdwadwadawdawdawdawddwawdadwdawdawdwadadwdadawdwdadwadawddawdwadawdadawd</div>
                <div class="slds-m-top_small slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_destructive">Show</button>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_success">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
    </div>
</template>
```